# How to make it so that when I type test.com it will open the files from b.test.com?

Tags: dns, hosting

We have two servers (with different IPs) which are hosting two different websites on them. We have the first site as the apex domain (`example.com`) and the second is a subdomain (`b.example.com`).

Right now `example.com` and `b.example.com` are completely different websites. How can I change this so that when I got to `example.com` it shows the same contents as `b.example.com` current shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess this depends on what you're trying to achieve. I am assuming that because you have `b.example.com` that is supposed to be the new "beta" site that you are now wanting to go live with.

If you want to swap to the new site then you should update the DNS `A` record for `example.com` to point at the same IP that `b.example.com` is pointing at.

This is one approach but I would recommend adding more detail to your question so that we can be more clear about what you're trying to achieve